# How do I quickly convert a block of text to an image in Open Office Writer?

Tags: microsoft-word, fonts, openoffice

I'm currently in a writing class doing short stories. As part of my story, I'm using custom fonts to represent specific languages. I'm writing everything with Open Office Writer, as I don't have MS Office at home. I can convert to a .pdf file to print it at the library, but I'm required to submit the files in .doc or .docx format. Additionally, the library doesn't allow me to install fonts, so I can't just use their software to embed the fonts using MS Word.

Open Office apparently has zero support for embedding custom fonts. So the next best thing is to rasterize the fonts and just embed an image in place of the alien text.

Is there a way to quickly convert inline text to inline images in Writer? Custom scripts, custom plugins, or built-in functionality are all acceptable.

Also helpful would be any way to embed a font directly into .doc files using either Writer with admin rights, or MS Word without admin rights, if such a thing is possible.

Comment: If you work on windows, then a workaround could be to use snipping tool to quickly convert paragraphs to picture. However it is efficient if you have only small part of document in that language.

Comment: Another tip: Word 365 is free for online use, have you tried that?